Rude or abusive flag description links to a redirecting page
In the dialog to flag a post, the description for the "Rude or abusive" reason is:

A reasonable person would find this content inappropriate for respectful discourse.

That link points to https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice which redirects you to https://stackoverflow.com/conduct.
Shouldn't the link in the description just point directly to
https://stackoverflow.com/conduct, or better yet, https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#unacceptable-behavior (the relevant section of that page)?

Honestly it could even link to https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#unacceptable-behavior . I'm not 100% thrilled with the flag description here since it doesn't include a really common use for rude flags: Unintelligible garbage. I kinda like Machavity's version in his feature request on Meta SE here. That's going a bit outside of this bug report (well, quite a bit outside of it), but I figure it's worth mentioning.

@Spevacus the link on the unfriendly/unkind and harassment/bigotry/abuse reasons for comment flags point to https://stackoverflow.com/conduct/abusive-behavior, maybe these too should be changed to https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#unacceptable-behavior ?
